# Unrecognized option "form" under "twig"のエラー

Tags: composer, twig, symfony

#### 前提・実現したいこと

PHP(Symfony)で既存のシステムのsymfonyアップデート(2.8->3.0)を行っております。
バージョンはすでに上がっており、現在フォルダ構造などを修正している状況です。
再度、composer updateをした際、下記のエラーが出ました。
formの指定方法が誤っているようですが、どこが違うのか分かりません。
ご教授のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

※本質問はteratailでも受け付けております。進捗がありましたら、こちらにも共有いたします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
[vagrant@localhost Symfony]$ php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update symfony/symfony
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository https://pear.php.net
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Package sensio/distribution-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package sensio/generator-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/maker-bundle instead.
Package twig/extensions is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
9 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
  Unrecognized option "form" under "twig"

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

    [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
    Unrecognized option "form" under "twig"
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```yml
# config.yml
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
```

#### 試したこと

下記サイトを参考にformを指定してみましたが、変わりませんでした。
https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/10477463
https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle/issues/85

```
twig:
    form: 
        resources:
            - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
```

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

CentOS 6.7
composer 1.10
symfony 3.0.9
PHP 5.6.40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記で該当配列を探して、参照urlの形 (form:からform_theme:の形にすることでエラーがなくなりました。)
`grep -r "twig:" src/* app/* --exclude="*.bak" |  grep -v ".svn"`

https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle/issues/85